# How to stream microphone audio over UDP with dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, udp, streaming

With my program, I need to be able to speak into 1 device and my voice play out another device. I was going to originally use TCP to do this, but then it was recommended to me that I should use UDP to reduce latency and make the audio sound better when it comes through. But as the title says, how can I take a dart Stream and send it through UDP? I know there is a function on a TCP `Socket` object from the `dart:io` library called `addStream()` that makes this easy, not 100% sure how it works, but I was wondering if there was something similar to this for UDP? I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream) library for recording audio, by the way. I'm not really sure what I'm doing and was hoping that someone could explain how to do this in dart, and hopefully this could help a wandering and desperate Googler. This is what I had for my program that used TCP:

```
void handleClient(Socket client) {
    print("Connected a client");
    client.addStream(_audioStream);
  }
  _audioStream = _recorder.audioStream.listen((data) { 
    if (_isRecording) {
      ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 4444)
      .then((ServerSocket server) {
        print("Server socket init");
        server.listen(handleClient);
      });
    }
  });
```

Again, this was the version that uses TCP, and of course this didn't work. I'm not really sure what I'm doing, but hopefully that should give you a good idea of what I'm trying to do. How do I send an audio stream over UDP with dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out almost 2+ years later. The latency isn't great and I'm still working on that. But to any lost and wandering Googlers, here you go:

You'll need the `mic_stream` and `flutter_sound` packages off pub.dev.

Sender side:

```
Stream<Uint8List>? stream = await MicStream.microphone(
      sampleRate: 32000,
      audioFormat: AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
    );
    int? bufferSize = await MicStream.bufferSize;
    RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port).then((socket) {
      StreamSubscription<List<int>> listener = stream!.listen((sample) async {
        socket.send(sample, InternetAddress(sendToAddress), port);
      });
    });
```

and the receiving side:

```
FlutterSoundPlayer player = FlutterSoundPlayer();
await player.openPlayer(enableVoiceProcessing: false);
    await player.startPlayerFromStream(
        codec: Codec.pcm16, numChannels: 1, sampleRate: 32000);
    var receiver = UDP.bind(
        Endpoint.unicast(InternetAddress(thisDeviceIPAddress), port: const Port(37069)));
    final udpSocket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(a5atHome, port);
    udpSocket.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
      Uint8List? data = udpSocket.receive()?.data;
      if (data != null) {
        player.foodSink!.add(FoodData(data)); // this plays the audio
      } else {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking here is essentially voice communication over the internet
check out
[WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) and its flutter implementation [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc)

Comment: Doesn't webrtc require a server of some sort between the two clients? I was hoping that 1 smartphone could host a device and pass audio between the two without an external host, or am I wrong?

Comment: which type of communication doesn't if you are communicating over the internet , or you should expose your another device to the internet essentially making it the server

Comment: do you happen to know any good resources to learn how to use webrtc with flutter, and also just using it for streaming audio? There is little documentation on the library, and there aren't many videos on youtube that explain how to use it in the way I'm looking for

Comment: Hi i’m also looking for additional information on WebRTC - does it allow to stream audio real time to back-end from Flutter App - how ? i would gladly up vote a well explained answer 